# During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: & google sheets not found

Tags: python, google-sheets

```py
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('Credentials.json',scope)
result = gspread.authorize(credentials)
res = result.open('A').sheet1
print(res.get_all_records())
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Umair\PycharmProjects\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 123, in open
    self.list_spreadsheet_files()
  File "C:\Users\Umair\PycharmProjects\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\gspread\utils.py", line 37, in finditem
    return next((item for item in seq if func(item)))
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Umair/PycharmProjects/Web/PhytonRandom.py", line 6, in <module>
    res = result.open('A').sheet1
  File "C:\Users\Umair\PycharmProjects\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 131, in open
    raise SpreadsheetNotFound
gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound
```

Comment: Make sure that the drive file you are trying to access actually exists. This error simply says that the sheet you are trying to open does exist.

Comment: i have created a new sheet but still gives me same error

Comment: Does it contain sheet named sheet1 ?... You can use the link https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/105217/gspread.authorize for more. :)

Comment: the error is on line res = result.open('A').sheet1 its

Comment: can you share the screenshot of this spreadsheet

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Fn0V9DpKAVLzpynfzAZVuoO_E_LuA40w

Comment: See the sheet you shared is still `Untitled` and you are passing name as `A` which does not exist, Hence the error

Comment: i renamed it but it still gives me same error

Comment: thanks brother the error has gone after renaming the name of sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [GSpread documentation](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.Client.open):

> `open(title)`
>   **Raises: gspread.SpreadsheetNotFound** – if no spreadsheet with specified title is found.

The Sheet title specified (in your code, `A`) has to exist in your account. Furthermore, the sheet with the name `Sheet1` must also be present so it can also be accessed by your line of code `res = result.open('A').sheet1`